# Dynamic 2d array in c++ and memory leaks

Tags: c++, dynamic, arrays, 2d, valgrind

I wrote this code. It runs OK, but when I check it under Valgrind it catches 2 problems. Since I can not interpret valgrind's messages i will appreciate if anyone explain me more and tell me where is the problem!!!

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

#define width  70000 
#define height 10000

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int** pint; 

    pint = new int*[height];
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        pint[i] = new int[width];

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        delete[] pint[i];
        pint[i] = NULL;
    }

    delete[] pint;
    pint = NULL;


    return 1;
}
```

Comment: What was valgrind's complaint?

Comment: We can't tell you what the valgrind problem is without seeing the complaints.

Comment: Perhaps post the valgrind messages - first glance, this code looks okay.

Comment: there was a ton of messages, how can i get all those message here?
can you run the code on you machine...?

Comment: Few of us are likely to have valgrind installed locally, but if you copy-paste the output into your question and tag it all as code, we'd have a better shot at it.

Comment: btw, if my calculations are right, this program will attempt to allocate ~2GB of memory. :-) it sure would be nice if valgrind complained about that and suggested switching to 64-bit mode.

Comment: by the way, is there any better option than valgrind? it looks weird to me.

Comment: it chose the big numbers to check the memory allocation and deallocations through System monitor(ubuntu).

Comment: Obligatory: Use `std::vector`, not memory allocations by hand.

Comment: The <edited> valgrind message I get when running this: \*\*2130\*\* new/new[] failed and should throw an exception, but cannot throw exceptions and so is aborting instead.  Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, there are a couple of Valgrind warnings I get with 3.4 but only the first is important.

> new/new[] failed and should throw an exception, but Valgrind cannot throw exceptions and so is aborting instead.  Sorry.

`new` throws an exception when it is out of memory (unless you use the nothrow version of new).  Unfortunately, Valgrind cannot handle that and gives up before your code completes.  Because valgrind aborts, you code to free up memory is never executed which shows up as memory leaks.

That said, you are not handling the case where new throws so your program will die due to an unhandled exception if you run out of memory.  You need to wrap your code with a try/except block.

Comment: At last valgrind is apologetic, Visual Studio never apologies when it crashes.

Answer (score 5):

It looks to me like it's complaining that some of the `new[]`s are failing. If you reduce the size of `height` and/or `width`, then it works fine. You're likely trying to allocate too much memory.

**EDIT**: That's on my 32-bit box. If I run it on my 64-bit box, it's fine. So, you're likely hitting a memory limit on a 32-bit machine.